# I need the results from more than one select statement, (using Limit (x) displayed in a table created by php echo

Tags: php, mysql, select

new to php and MYSQL,and would like some help, so please be gentle
I have some code which populates a HTML table using php echo.
The statement is:

```
$query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
        FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
        WHERE Year = '7'  
        and Stroke = 'Freestyle' order by Time Asc Limit 1" ;
```

I would like to add more select statements. The idea is that by using Order  bt Time ASC and Limit 1 for each select statement, the single table will display the fastest entry for each style, e.g. one entry for Freestyle, one entry for Backstroke etc.

```
$query2= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
          FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
          WHERE Year = '7'  
          and Stroke = 'Backstroke' order by Time Asc Limit 1" ;
```

Thanks in advance

From research it look like I may need an array, (not a join),  but  I am struggling at this point.
Here is my current code:

```
<?php

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                        Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
                FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
                WHERE Year = '7'  
                and Stroke = 'Freestyle' Order by Time ASC" ;  

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);     
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (count($result) > 0) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo '<table class="special-table">';
            echo '<thead class="fixed-header">';
            echo '<tr>
                <th>Pos.</th>
                <th class="left-align">Name</th>
                <th class="left-align">Stroke</th>
                <th>Yr</th>
                <th>Dist</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>AgeGrp</th>
                <th>Gen.</th>
                <th>DAte</th>
                <th>Event</th>
                </tr></thead><tbody>';
                
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td >" . $cnt++ ."</td>
                            <td class='left-align'>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>
                            <td class='left-align'>" . $row["Stroke"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["Year"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["Dist"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["Time"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["AgeGrp"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["Gender"] . "</td>
                            <td >" . Date('d-m-y', strtotime($row['Date'])) . "</td>
                            <td >" . $row["Event"] . "</td>
                        </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table></div>";
          } else {
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<div style='font-size: 42px;'>  No results found ";
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    // Close the database connection
    $pdo = null;
?>
```

Comment: Note also how nicely indented code with a few blank lines is so much easier to read. That will also make it easier to debug, or maintain when you come back to this code in a month to add something new

Comment: It is often helpful to contributors if askers provide a sandbox demo link with sufficient sample data so that potential solutions can be tested for accuracy before posting an answer. @bgarcher

Comment: "I am struggling at this point" - struggling with...? With setting the proper query, with evaluting it properly, with printing the expected table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no ties in Time per Stroke you can use this approach:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM JLSSWIMMING1
WHERE (Year, Stroke, Dist, Time) IN (
    SELECT Year, Stroke, Dist, MIN(Time)
    FROM JLSSWIMMING1
    WHERE Year = 7
    GROUP BY Stroke, Dist
);
```

Or, using the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html), you could:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Stroke, Dist ORDER BY Time) AS rn
    FROM JLSSWIMMING1
    WHERE Year = 7
) AS tmp
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ed5GC5ky).

Comment: These are great, and I don't want to sound ungrateful, I forgot to add distance in my original example.
The table JLSSWIMMING1 contains a field called Dist, 25.50. and 100, so a typical record looks like this:
Gender Distance Stroke Year First Name Family Name House Time
Girl        25        Freestyle 7 Emma  Conner        Big     10.00
I've tried to amend your solutions to include Dist, but at present they are a bit over my head
Still don't know how to format my questions properly

Comment: Does that mean you want to return a row for each distance for each stroke?

Comment: Yes, the results will show the time and distance for each stroke, e.g.
One Row for Backstroke to include time and distance
One Row for Freestyle to include tame and distance

Comment: I have added `Dist` to the two example queries. If this is not what you want, please update your question with sample data and desired output. [Help with formatting can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I added Dist to both queries and updated the fiddle

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back, Yes the latest solution works  I hope the formatting of my reply is better  db<>fiddle looks great, didn't know it existed

Answer (score 1):

Use one query like this to get all the data you want in one select. You should always try to exercise the power of a query rather than treat a relational database like a flat file.

```
$query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
        FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
        WHERE Year = '7'  
        and ( Stroke = 'Freestyle' OR Stroke = 'Backstroke')";
```

Or you could use the IN() clause like this

```
$query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
        FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
        WHERE Year = '7'  
        and Stroke IN('Freestyle', 'Backstroke')";
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post, that was such an easy solution,
Thank you, I used the first suggestion, . How do mark this post as answered?

Comment: For future reference how do I format the information as you have done.
My initial post was a copy and paste

Comment: Format you actual code. Set your editor to us 4 spaces when you hit TAB and use a decent code exitor for example VSCode which is free

Comment: OK, I've just realised my initial problem wasn't what I thought it was, and the solution is great but not what I actually needed.
The problem I have is still related, do I raise another question or add it to this one?

Comment: I really do need 2 statements, because I intend to use Limit (x) to get the top entry from each style, so for example
query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
          Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
          FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
          WHERE Year = '7'  
          and Stroke = 'Backstroke' Limit 1" ;
AND
query2= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
          Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
          FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
          WHERE Year = '7'  
          and Stroke = 'Freestyle' Limit 1" ;

Comment: @bgarcher Please update your question to clarify what you need to achieve. What do you mean by _"top entry from each style"_? To get a meaningful result with limit you should be specifying an order by clause. Adding some rows of sample data and your desired result might help.

Comment: Firstly thanks for your patience,.
The statement will look this:
$query= "SELECT Distinct AgeGrp, Gender,Dist, Stroke, First, 
                Family, Name, Year, Time, Event, Date 
        FROM JLSSWIMMING1 
        WHERE Year = '7'  
        and ( Stroke = 'Freestyle') ORDER by Time ASC limit 1";
This will give the the top entry for the Freestyle stroke.
I need to replicate this statement for other styles. so my table has the top entry for Freestyle,Breast stroke, etc